# How can I enable BUILTIN\Administrators for my user

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-permissions

I am working in an Windows active directory environment.

I am connected to a windows workstation with a domain user.

Here is what I see when I type:

whoami /groups

```
BUILTIN\Administrators      Alias     S-XXXXX              Group used for deny only
```

I have a local administrator account too and a domain administrator account.
I have tried to add my user to this group. I have also tried to remove it from the group and add it again (with "net localgroup groupname username /add") command.

It does not work. My user is still present in this "Deny" group.

How can I add my user to Administrators group ?

Thanks

Comment: The "deny" is part of User Account Control. You can read up on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works

Comment: UAC works with access tokens ? I do not understand why groups are involved...

Comment: Looks like you may be seeing the "deny only" comment due to how you're viewing `whoami`, not a permissions thing as such. See https://blogs.infosupport.com/uac-and-tokens/ which matches what I see, eg if I run `whoami /groups` from an elevated cmd prompt I get "Mandatory Group, Enabled by default, Enabled group" instead of "Group used for deny only".

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you fail to run this command at an elevated command prompt (opening it with "run as admin"), you get this response even if your user IS in the admin group. It's easy to be misled by this. (Keith was conveying this in his comment, but since some folks don't read comments but only answers, I thought it warranted being clarified as an answer.)

Further, if instead you CANNOT open an elevated command prompt then in fact you are NOT in the admin group.

And to your original question of how to add yourself to the admin group, well, you can't. Only an Admin (or a member of the admin group) can. That said, you can find various discussions on the web of ways to try to get around this problem. Some are hacks, and some may work only in certain situations, while others are trying to sell tools (caveat emptor).